# Whitehead Lemma

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology

I'm looking for a proof of the $1^{st}$ Whitehead lemma.

> $1^{st}$ Whitehead lemma:
>
> If $L$ is a Lie Algebra which is semisimple, then for any finite dimensional representation $(V,\rho)$ of $L$, $H^1(L,V,\rho) = \{0\}$

I cannot find any proof on the internet. If someone knows where I can find one...

Answer (score 0):

There is a proof [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~reichst/Lie-Algebra-Cohomology.pdf). I did not read it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proof using [Weyl's Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516407/proof-of-weyls-theorem-humphreys). And the proof of Weyl's Theorem can be found on the internet, even on MSE.
So we know that every finite-dimensional $L$-module of a semisimple Lie algebra over $K$ is semisimple, i.e., has a module complement. Hence all module extensions are trivial, and we have
$$
0 = {\rm Ext}(B,A) = H^1(L; {\rm Hom}(B,A))
$$
for each pair of finite-dimensional $L$-moduls $A$ and $B$. In particualr, we obtain for $B=K$, the trivial module, 
$$
H^1(L,A)=0
$$
for all finite-dimensional $L$-modules $A$.