# Every derivative $\delta : L \to L $ for finite semisimple Lie algebra $L$ over $\Bbb C $ is inner automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

I need to show that Every derivative $\delta : L \to L $ for finite semisimple Lie algebra $L$ over $\Bbb C $ is inner automorphism.

when Inner automorphism is defined by 
$exp(ad_x)= \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}  ad_x^j/j!$

when $ad_x$ nilpotent with nilpotent degree of $k$

for all $x \in L$
when $ad_x:L \to L , ad_x(y)=[x,y] $

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2297553/whitehead-lemma

Comment: $Der(L)=ad(L)$, so all derivations are inner.